# Problem with deployment a multiple pages react-app

Tags: javascript, github, deployment, react-router, react-router-dom

There is a problem deploying a React app which contains multiple pages mean system of routes. When it deployed the components are not shown in the browser.

```json
"homepage": "https://FaisalCodeCraft.github.io/mount__sleet"
```

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/mount_sleet">
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/mount_sleet" element={<Home />}>
  </Route>
</BrowserRouter>
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is being served or hosted from `"https://FaisalCodeCraft.github.io/mount__sleet"`, e.g. a `"/mount__sleet"` directory with ***two*** underscores, then the router's `basename` prop should match this exactly, e.g. `basename="/mount__sleet"`. This also now means that ***all*** routes and links will function *relative* to this base path, so you can remove the `"mount_sleet"` from the home page page unless you really do want its path to be `"https://FaisalCodeCraft.github.io/mount__sleet/mount__sleet"`.

Example:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/mount__sleet">
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  </Route>
</BrowserRouter>
```

If the routing/navigation still isn't working as expected, then you may need to switch to the `HashRouter` so the app works correctly on Github pages (*see my answer [here](https:///a/71985764/8690857) for more details*).

```
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<HashRouter basename="/mount__sleet">
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  </Route>
</HashRouter>
```